# How do I register a file association in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, mime, file-association

I'm in the process of creating a Ubuntu Installer and I need to register my own file extension  I cant find any examples of how to do this.

Could people provide me with some script snippets on how to do this?

NB: Im using [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) to help me create the installer, which allows me to call external scripts - so that is why a script would be beneficial.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580345/ubuntu-fedora-how-do-i-add-applications-in-the-menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An InstallJammer installer won't integrate very well with the distribution, but here goes.

Use [xdg-mime](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=xdg-mime) install and xdg-mime default to set up the mimetype and associate it.

Comment: Thanks Ill have alook. When you say its wont integrate well with the distribution, what do you mean?

Comment: Debian packages can get installed, removed, upgraded (including conffile updates), and in general reliably managed. They have their files and documentation in certain expected places. Your installer is a one-off and it won't be as well supported or as convenient to administer.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to write an ubuntu package, for example with CDBS ([overview](http://debathena.mit.edu/packaging/), [docs](http://cdbs-doc.duckcorp.org/en/cdbs-doc.xhtml#id450257), [examples](http://cdbs.ueberalles.net/_list.html), [bonus non-cdbs tutorial](http://www.offbyzero.com/resources/java_deb_ubuntu)).

Then you add `$PACKAGE.sharedmimeinfo` and `$APPNAME.desktop` files in the debian/ directory. The sharedmimeinfo file describes the file type, the desktop file describes your app. The latter should contain a `MimeType=application/x-$APPNAME;` that matches the filetype.

Comment: this might help also: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/