# How to register a "Linux" file association with autotools

Tags: gnome, autotools, file-association, xdgutils, freedesktop.org

I'm writing an application that uses its own file type. I'd like to integrate the file association with the desktop environment. I know that this can be done [with a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042680/how-do-i-register-a-file-association-in-ubuntu#tab-top), but how should it be integrated with autotools?

Currently, my app can be installed without root to `~/.local` for example. It would be nice to keep this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `myapp.xml` to your project that contains the desired MIME data. It'll look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
  <mime-type type="image/png">
     <comment xml:lang="en">PNG image</comment>
     <comment xml:lang="af">png beeld</comment>
     ...
     <magic priority="50">
            <match type="string" value="\x89PNG" offset="0"/>
     </magic>
     <glob pattern="*.png"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

See [the tutorial](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor) for more details on the format of the XML files.

Now you need to figure out where to install your XML file to.  In my projects, I provide a `--with-xdgdatadir` option to `configure`, which is left as an exercise to the reader.  By default, `XDGDATADIR` should be `${prefix}/share` (i.e. `${datarootdir}`).  Add the following to your `Makefile.am`:

```
xdgdatadir=@XDGDATADIR@
mimedir=$(xdgdatadir)/mime
xmldir=$(mimedir)/packages
xml_DATA = myapp.xml
```

This will ensure that the MIME data is installed correctly.

Finally, it's necessary to ensure that the MIME database is updated on `make install` and `make uninstall`. Add a check for the `update-mime-database` tool to your `configure.ac`.  Then add the following to your `Makefile.am`:

```
install-data-hook:
    $(UPDATE_MIME_DATABASE) "$(DESTDIR)$(mimedir)"

uninstall-hook:
    $(UPDATE_MIME_DATABASE) "$(DESTDIR)$(mimedir)"
```

I hope that answers your question.